# Solve this equation: $7x^3+11x^2+6x+2=(x+2)\sqrt[3]{x^3+3x^2+5x+1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, radicals

Solve this equation: $7x^3+11x^2+6x+2=(x+2)\sqrt[3]{x^3+3x^2+5x+1}$

---

I used Wolframalpha.com and get solutions $x\in\left\{0; \dfrac{-9\pm\sqrt{53}}{14}\right\}$.
But I can't solve this.

Comment: Does the op have reason to believe this is easily solvable?

Comment: @Zach466920 Just a piece of advice to you: You need to calm down on your wording to relatively new users.  This is a site where people can ask questions about mathematics (no matter how ridiculous you may think they are) and receive some type of response (or none at all).  If you feel that a user needs to learn some more about how the site works, please refer them to one (or many) of the numerous pages devoted to explaining what is expected of the users on the Math.SE community.

Comment: You don't seem to have made an attempt at this. You need to add motivation for why a solution is needed...

Comment: @jnh Advice taken, my point remains unchanged...Here's some advice to you. When you decide to try and give advice on what's an acceptable question, check to see if said "question" has a question mark anywhere in it ;). To clarify, it makes what you just said irrelevant seeing as by definition this is not a question...

Comment: @Zach466920 As I stated previously, refer the user to some documentation about what is expected of new users on Math.SE.  Also, I do not believe I stated anywhere in my previous comment that this was an "acceptable" answer did I?  Since you made it you're point in your first comment (which is now deleted) to make a big deal about the OP putting forth no effort and calling the situation "ridiculous", you could have just as easily referred OP to said documentation.  We are all here to help and help others improve the quality of posts.

Comment: @jnh Firstly, I never mention the answer to this question in any of my comments.  Secondly, Op clearly knows how to format, so there was much reason to assume he knows what kind of questions are well received on the site. Finally, I see that despite your insistence on the importance of referencing the site's manual, you've still failed to do so...

Comment: At the Op, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) are the guidelines for good questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $t = \sqrt[3]{x^3+3x^2+5x+1}.$
We have system of equations
$$\begin{cases}
7 x^3 + 11 x^2 + 6 x + 2=(x+2)t,\\
t^3 = x^3+3x^2+5x+1.
\end{cases}$$
Minus two equations, we get
$$(-1 + t - 2 x)(4 x^2+(5 + 2 t) x+3 + t + t^2)=0.$$

The equation
$$4 x^2+(5 + 2 t) x+3 + t + t^2=0$$
with unknown $x$ has discriminant is $-12 t^2+4 t-23$ negative for all $t$, therefore has no sulution.

The equation $-1 + t - 2 x = 0$ or
$$\sqrt[3]{x^3+3 x^2+5 x+1}=2x+1$$ 
has three solutions $$x=0\lor x=\frac{1}{14}\left(-9-\sqrt{53}\right)\lor x=\frac{1}{14}\left(\sqrt{53}-9\right).$$

Answer (score 3):

$7x^3+11x^2+6x+2 = (x+1)(7x^2+4x+2)$

$x^3+3x^2+5x+1 = (x+1)^3+2x$

Raising both sides to the $3$rd power:

$$(x+1)^3(7x^2+4x+2)^3=(x+2)^3((x+1)^3+2x) \implies \\ (x+1)^3(7x^2+4x+2)^3 - (x+2)^3(x+1)^3 - 2x(x+2)^3=0 \implies \\ (x+1)^3((7x^2+4x+2)^3-(x+2)^3) -2x(x+2)^3 = 0 \implies \\ x(x+1)^3(7x+3)(49x^4+63x^3+63x^2+30x+12) - 2x(x+2)^3 = 0 \implies \\ x (7 x^2+9 x+1) (49 x^6+168 x^5+266 x^4+262 x^3+175 x^2+78 x+20) = 0  $$

$x = 0$ is a solution, and $7x^2+9x+1 = 0$ is a solution. Compute the discriminant and find the roots.

Let $f(x) = 49 x^6+168 x^5+266 x^4+262 x^3+175 x^2+78 x+20$

$f'(x) = 294 x^5+840 x^4+1064 x^3+786 x^2+350 x+78$

$f''(x) = 2 (175 + 786 x + 1596 x^2 + 1680 x^3 + 735 x^4)$

$f'''(x) = 12 (131 + 532 x + 840 x^2 + 490 x^3)$

$f''''(x) = 168 (38 + 120 x + 105 x^2)$

$f''''$ is positive everywhere (compute discriminant, find that it is negative, etc.). So $f'''$ is increasing. Note that $f'''$ has exactly one root call it $\alpha$. Convince yourself that $f''(\alpha) > 0$ to deduce that $f'' > 0$ everywhere (or prove it, it is a good exercise). Continue until you reach the fact that $f > 0$ everywhere, so it contributes no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

When disappear the radical the resulting equation is of degree 9 then, because **C** is algebraically closed, there are 9 roots (with eventual multiplicity). We know already 3 given by “idiots” and I admit my inability to calculate for myself directly the other 6 corresponding to the irreducible polynomial given by BolzWeir here. By computation they are with approximation (a, b)  = (-1.0243, ±0.2351√(-1) ), (-0.1147, ±0.7073√(-1) ), (-0.5753, ±0.6236√(-1)).